# Word vsto get text of document with hidden characters

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm developing a text analysis vsto add-in for Word.
Therefore I get the text of the active document like this:

```
Globals.ThisAddin.Apllication.ActiveDocument.Content.Text
```

After that I analyze it. The analysis returns a list of positions that Word should comment (like character 3 - 6 and character 10 - 13).

The problem is that it seems like the comment from 3 to 6 is adding a character (that is hidden) to the document. Because all comments that Word is doing after the first one are placed one character too early.

Is there a way how I can fix that or how I can get the text with the hidden characters?

I found `TextRetrievalMode` but I can not get it working with that.

Comment: Sometimes it is just easier to work with the object model than against it.  You don't say how you are identifying text to which you are adding a comment.

Comment: I m using regex and some calculations on indices. That gives me the positions of some areas I have to comment. Do you think I should work directly with Ranges?

Comment: That's a difficult question to answer because its not clear what you mean by comment or whether or not you are generating a separate text file or wishing to add the comments to the original word file.  If you wish your comments to appear in the word document then working with the object model is likely to be easier.  Remember that you can do wildcard searches in a word document using the find method so unless you have something that specifically drives you to use RegEx on extracted text that may be your most reasonable solution.

Comment: Yes I need to use Regex... Do you know if there is a hidden char when a comment is inserted in a document?

Comment: Why don't you check yourself.  Just create a word document with a short amount of text and no comments.  Iterate the text character by character to see what values get  reported for each character.  Then do the same having inserted 1 or 2 or more comments.

Comment: I have done debugging on it with a string diff checker but the text I get with the method I described in my post is always the same. Thats why I was wondering if there is a way to ger the hidden things too. I think it has something todo with the textretrievalmode

Comment: Nothing more I can contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the answer is "No, you can't do it the way you propose."

Yes, Word does add "hidden characters" to the text flow that cannot be picked up using the object model. Trying to work with character index values is not going to work reliably. The reliable method is Word's built-in Find/Replace with wildcards. If RegEx is absolutely necessary, then some kind of Find/Replace within a character-index range (say, starting 5 characters before and ending 5 characters after the indices computed using RegEx) might be a way to double-check the result and pick up the correct Range.

Possibly, depending on what kind of analysis this is, it might be better to work with the closed file, leveraging the Office Open XML. That will not have the problem of "hidden characters" that Word uses for structural information. On the other hand, there's a lot of formatting information that breaks up text runs that needs to be contended with...

Comment: Ok thx. Another thing I thought about is counting the comments in front of the character I want to comment and then add the number to the indices

Comment: @huckjulius Not sure I'm following your thought, above... Do you mean if there are three comments preceding to add three to the index the analysis comes up with? No, not a good idea - Word does the same thing ("hidden characters") with other content, not just comments. ContentControls are another example.

Comment: Good point... there will be too many problems. But I know that there won t be other things except comments. But I know that that is not a good solution. Do you know what the TextRetrievalMode is and how to use it?

Comment: `TextRetrievalMode` is for the "hidden" things that can actually be accessed by the user and the object model: specifically field codes and text with "hidden" font formatting. In the object model, these can be selectively included / left out of the content returned by a `Range` object, regardless of whether they're displayed on-screen to the user. But it does not interact with hidden "structures" stored in the document. @huckjulius